# How to open bookmarklet in Internet explorer popup window

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, popup, popupwindow, bookmarklet

I have developed the Bookmarklet for Internet Explorer. It works fine when user load it on main browser page.
The issue is, it does not work on the Pop-Up Window of the application.

Most of my users, open the link inside the main page in pop-up, but the bookmarklet is triggered from Favorite window.

The bookmarklet link is not working in pop-up window.

Is there a way to achieve this ?

Comment: because the pop up window does not have a toolbar on it??

Comment: I tried enabling favorates bar on popup and tried, but still the bookmarklet was not getting added in popup window

Answer (score 1):

Try to use code below may help to solve your issue.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8" />
<title>WhatsApp</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
javascript:(function(){open('https://Microsoft.com/','myWindow','toolbar=yes, menubar=yes, resizable=yes, width=650,height=900,top=0,left=1270');})()
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, but i cannot control how the popup is been opened. I need some way in which pop-up opened from any sites should allow bookmark. I tried "always open pop-ups in a new window ie11"

Comment: @ lopes rohan, Is opening the pop ups in new window solve your issue?